# How can Customizing the Scroll Bar in Android

Tags: android, customization, scrollview

I trying to build an custom scroll view like showing in attached pic.

can any body have any suggestion , pls let me know.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these attribs of the `Scrollview` class.

> `android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal`    -   Defines the horizontal scrollbar thumb drawable. 
>   `android:scrollbarThumbVertical`    -   Defines the vertical scrollbar thumb drawable.

Comment: thanks, i already check this property , but using it i am able to set color only not any Bitmap image with scroll view.

Comment: It says the thumb drawable not color. You need to convert it to a `BitmapDrawable` before setting it in java code.

Comment: yes i did same now ...it showing on screen but not working with Scroll view it self.

Comment: add `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` to your listView.

Comment: These don't change the fast scroll thumb though.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna add thumb scroller, you may need to add[`android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3afastScrollEnabled) to your list view

Don't forget to check at [SectionIndexer](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html)

You might wanna take a look at [RingsExtended](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/RingsExtended) project at [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/)